# How to format chat conversations in markdowntextblock in Windows Universal application (windows 10)

Tags: c#, xaml, markdown, uwp-xaml

I am building a chat application in which i have below xaml code -

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Black">
<Grid Background="White" Name="mainGrid">

    <Border  BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="0.2" Margin="3,0,3,3">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:MarkdownTextBlock Name="markdownBlock" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe-UI">
                    </controls:MarkdownTextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I use below code in my code behind to send text to the MarkdownTextBlock control

```
            messages.Add(new Message() { Text = "**Person 1:** " + message });
```

and the  response -

```
            messages.Add(new Message() { Text = "**Person 2:** " + activity.Text });
```

Right now the format is plain background like below -

**Person 1:** Hello, How are you doing?

**Person 2:** Hi, I am doing great!

How can i format these plain messages to get conversation feel like we have in skype as

[image]

I am new to Windows Application development, I am not sure how to format the text as conversations within markdown text block, could you guide me?

Do I need to create a table within markdown control and pass the messages by having background color on rows? not sure how to do this. Any help?

Updated view -

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gif="using:XamlAnimatedGif"   
    xmlns:local="using:LISA_Speech1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Black">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MessageItemStyle" TargetType="SelectorItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="450" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>

        <Style
        x:Key="RightAlignedMessageStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageItemStyle}"
        TargetType="SelectorItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </Style>

        <Style
        x:Key="LeftAlignedMessageStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageItemStyle}"
        TargetType="SelectorItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>

        <styleSelectors:MessageContainerStyleSelector
        x:Key="MessageContainerStyleSelector"
        ReceivedStyle="{StaticResource LeftAlignedMessageStyle}"
        Sender="{x:Bind CurrentUser, Mode=OneWay}"
        SentStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignedMessageStyle}" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageTemplate" x:DataType="messages:Message">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock
                Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                Text="{x:Bind Message, Mode=OneWay}"
                TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />

                <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{x:Bind SentDate, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MessageItemPanelTemplate">
            <ItemsStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Black" Name="mainGrid">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border  BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="0.2" Margin="3,0,3,3">
            <ListView
    x:Name="Messages"
    Margin="10"
    CanDrag="False"
    CanReorderItems="False"
    IsItemClickEnabled="False"
    IsTapEnabled="False"
    ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MessageContainerStyleSelector}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplate}"
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MessageItemPanelTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Border>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="text" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyDown" Grid.Column="0" PlaceholderText="Type something or say 'Start Listening'" FontSize="17" BorderBrush="Purple" Margin="0,10,0,-7" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            </TextBox>

            <Button x:Name="button" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Column="1" Height="58" Width="35" Padding="0" Background="Purple" Margin="0,10,0,-7">
                <SymbolIcon x:Name="symbol" Symbol="Microphone" Width="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="-2,-8,-2,-2"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>


        <MediaElement x:Name="Media"></MediaElement>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this quite simple using an ItemContainerStyleSelector. What this will do is allow you to create some logic that takes your chat message object and determine if it was sent or received.

For example, your model may look like this:

```
public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string UserTo { get; set; }

    public string UserFrom { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
}
```

You then will create the StyleSelector like this:

```
public class MessageContainerStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style SentStyle { get; set; }

    public Style ReceivedStyle { get; set; }

    public string Sender { get; set; }

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var message = item as Message;
        if (message != null)
        {
            return message.UserFrom.Equals(this.Sender, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                       ? this.SentStyle
                       : this.ReceivedStyle;
        }

        return base.SelectStyleCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

From here, we then need to create the styles that will be used with this style selector and they are very simple. They will also give you flexibility for the colors you're looking to use for the sent or received messages.

In your view, you may have styles set up like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MessageItemStyle" TargetType="SelectorItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="450" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>

    <Style
        x:Key="RightAlignedMessageStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageItemStyle}"
        TargetType="SelectorItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>

    <Style
        x:Key="LeftAlignedMessageStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageItemStyle}"
        TargetType="SelectorItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>

    <styleSelectors:MessageContainerStyleSelector
        x:Key="MessageContainerStyleSelector"
        ReceivedStyle="{StaticResource LeftAlignedMessageStyle}"
        Sender="{x:Bind CurrentUser, Mode=OneWay}"
        SentStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignedMessageStyle}" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageTemplate" x:DataType="messages:Message">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock
                Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                Text="{x:Bind Message, Mode=OneWay}"
                TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />

            <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{x:Bind SentDate, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MessageItemPanelTemplate">
        <ItemsStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

In these styles, you see that we are using a base style which the two chat message styles inherit from. We are using a right/left alignment in this scenario so your messages will show on either side of the screen but here you can customize each style to your own needs.

A few other things to point out here, we are also declaring the DataTemplate that will be used to show layout the message. Notice here we aren't doing anything custom. Every message will layout the same, it's the container style that will alter how they appear in the ListView.

Also the ItemsPanelTemplate at the bottom allows the ListView to present the messages bottom up in a chat style format.

In regards to how this all ties together with your ListView in the page, you would now use the MessageContainerStyleSelector like this:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="Messages"
    Margin="10"
    CanDrag="False"
    CanReorderItems="False"
    IsItemClickEnabled="False"
    IsTapEnabled="False"
    ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MessageContainerStyleSelector}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplate}"
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MessageItemPanelTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Messages, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

When you're running the app, you'll get something that looks similar to this:

[image: UWP chat messaging]

Hopefully this is something to go off and you can take this further with this detail. Feel free to ask any questions, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Had been searching for an answer on this but found it very difficult. Could the tags on this question be updated to cover UWP? I only managed to find this by searching for Windows 10!

Comment: Thanks a lot James.. I will try this out today and let you know.

Comment: Hi James, I followed as suggested by you.. But I am facing few issues with the code - design view breaks with invalid markup. I get errors on <styleSelectors:MessageContainerStyleSelector> , <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageTemplate" x:DataType="messages:Message"> and <ItemsStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView" />.. I am not sure what am I missing. I just changed "Message" field name with "Text" as per my code behind. could you please help me what am I missing?

Comment: @SatheeshPanduga you may need to add the styleSelectors and messages namespaces at the top of your page. e.g.     xmlns:styleSelectors="using:MyProject.Selectors".

Comment: Hi James, After adding the namespaces as you suggested.. I get below error Cannot assign text value 'KeepLastItemInView' into property 'ItemsUpdatingScrollMode' of type 'ItemsUpdatingScrollMode'.. It is for <ItemsPanelTemplate>. Could you please help? Also, I wanted to use markdown textblock instead of Textblock, I will try this as soon as I clear the error that I have with ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: @SatheeshPanduga what the issue may be is that the project you're attempting to build is not targeting the Anniversary Update SDK. The KeepLastItemInView is only available for that version. You will need to set both the Min and Target versions in your project's properties.

Comment: Hi James, thank you again.. Unfortunately, in my office environment - anniversary update is not available yet.. can we use anything else instead of KeepLastItemInView? Also, if you dont mind, could you please upload your code in github?

Comment: @SatheeshPanduga that's a shame, the Windows 10 Anniversary Update allows this feature. You can use one of the two other enum values available though which you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemsupdatingscrollmode).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is a custom control called `MessageViewer`. In this one you could have a parameter that tells you what's the direction of the message, or just two another classes `MessageViewerIn` and `MessageViewerOut` that could be like this:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightBlue" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15"></Rectangle>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Text="Some dummy text here"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Now, via code you could understand if you need an image on the LEFT or RIGHT column of this grid. Everything will depend if the text you're showing is from an user or if YOU are sending this text.
So, you could add some methods to check it (or directly do in in the constructor of this class like:

```
MessageViewer(String message, bool orientation)
MessageViewer msgVwr = new MessageViewer("Your Text", true/false)
```

...and if its `true` your icon will be on the left, and when it's false on the right. Inside of the control you can access various element, so for example, if you'll give a name for a grid

```
<Grid Name="grdMain">
```

you can acces his properties via code, like grdMain.Background, and set it and change it.

For the space on the left/right you could use margins of the interlat textbox, setted on "10, 10, 30, 10" for right-space (yours) messages and "30, 10, 10, 10" for left-space (incoming) messages.

For doing some text work, like bold or other, check out elements you can put inside a grid: everything you want :)

All this elements you could put in a simple `ListView` to show them like a chat.

Comment: Thanks Martinocom, I will check this as well.